# Event Driven Simulation: Confusion

Tags: verilog

I was reading about event driven simulation. Such simulations proceed after we have an 'event' which is the change in any signal value at the input of any design being simulated. The list of all the changed signals is added to what is called an 'event queue'. An 'event driver' then figures out what gates have these signals (inside the event queue) as input which in turn is passed to a 'gate driver'which calculates the output of the gates and stores the output in the new event queue. This constitutes one time step at the end of which signals in the event queue are assigned to the respective nets.
(For further details:http://cs.baylor.edu/~maurer/aida/desauto/chapter3.pdf)

Thus, I inferred that the signal assignments to the nets are always done at the end of each time step.

```
always @ (a or b or c)
begin
x = a | b;
y = a ^ b ^ c;
z = b & ~c;
end
```

Since in blocking assignments evaluation and assignments are immediate. Does this mean that say if `a` changes then each assignment will take place in one time step and hence the whole series of assignments, of `x`, `y` and `z`, takes three time steps?
Further, since it is an event driven simulation. If only `c` changes, the assignment of `x` will not take place, since there is no `c` in the inputs, and the assignments will take two time steps?
**EDIT**
Based on the answer below I agree that the assignments will be happening in a single time step. But consider the circuit below:
[image]

In the document I mentioned it is said that the assignments at C and Q will take place in two time steps. But suppose I code the circuit as follows:

```
always @ (A or B)
begin
C=~B;
Q=A&C;
end
```

Shouldn't the assignments at C and Q take place in a single time step?

Comment: The gold standard for this is the model VHDL uses, which guarantees determinism. Understanding it might help you understand the Verilog approach somewhat better.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532 Sorry I can't help with the specifics of Verilog but I suggest searching "Cliff Cummins non-blocking assignments" to find his authoritative paper on it.

Answer (score 3):

Verilog, is a **hardware descriptive language**. So think from hardware perspective which, in the ideal case do not have any delays (though setup,hold etc. many delays are present).

Referring the code snippet, the `always` block will execute whenever there is any change in **either** `a` **or** `b` **or** `c`.

> A blocking statement must be executed **before** the execution of the statements that **follow it** in a sequential block.
>
> Non blocking statements allow you to **schedule** assignments without blocking the procedural flow.

Blocking and non-blocking assignments are better understood by following example:

```
x = #10 5;   // x = 5 at time 10ns
y = #5  6;   // y = 6 at time 15ns

x <= #10 5;  // y = 6 at time 10ns
y <= #5  6;  // y = 6 at time 5ns
```

Here, in **blocking assignment**, `y` is evaluated after `x` is assigned a value. While using **non-blocking assignment**, `x` and `y` are evaluated and pushed into *simulators internal queue* and assigned at 10ns and 5ns respectively.

A blocking assignment effects **immediately**. A nonblocking assignment takes place at the **end of processing the current** "time delta".

In Verilog, there is a well defined **event queue** as shown below. For each and **every timestamp**, **all the regions are evaluated**. If there are any events to be executed in current timestamp, then they are *triggered*. Once all the events of current timestamp are *triggered*, then only simulation time moves forward.

[image: Verilog Event Regions]

Coming to your example, if `a` changes, `always` block is triggered and **ALL** the statements are in `always` block are executed. `x`, `y`,`z` are assigned the values immediately. This all happens in **ACTIVE REGION** of **same timestamp**. Even one of he variable in sensitivity list changes, *all* the statements are in the block are executed.

Refer [Blocking-Nonblocking difference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91688/difference-between-blocking-and-nonblocking-assignment-verilog), [Cummings_Verilog_Nonblocking](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjGnsbUgKnJAhXiKaYKHeygARsQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.437.3361%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNH1uFffM1u3NAWkKJ1FTWEq4C-B5g&sig2=76XOgCVczWVCt4PgbeRfDA&bvm=bv.108194040,d.dGY) paper, and [Event Regions](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi9mIPsgKnJAhXi4KYKHcjpC7MQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.211.4651%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNE4i_v2PFo_jIqp21QABPbpIYZuKA&sig2=miRd-IkkqmIiqScgTGqEfA&bvm=bv.108194040,d.dGY) paper for further information.

**EDIT:**

The pdf Page-7 says :

> the basic event-driven technique provides a unit-delay model, in which the delay of each gate is **assumed** to be **one**.

**The Unit delay Model** assumes implicit 1 timestamp delay for calculation output of every gate. This is indeed *true*, since physical hardware shall have certain finite delay, thus justifying:

> Simulated time increases by one for each subsequent execution of the Event Processor.

Also, this is just a **general assumption**, the time unit of delay varies according to time scale. While the above code refers to **ideal** **condition** output that a simulator shall produce (that is, with zero gate delay).

Referring to PDF again:

> The two-phase structure of the event-driven simulation algorithm imposes a time scale on the simulation...It is usually assumed that an **arbitrary** number of **simulated time units** can occur between successive input vectors.

For the **circuit**, if **both** A and B changes, then according to event driven simulation model, G2 is evaluated since A has changed, at lets say at  **0ns**. Along with G2, G1 is also evaluated due to B at **0ns**. Thereafter, G2 is evaluated once again due to C at **1ns**, producing output at **2ns**.

If either A or B changes, then G2 is evaluated once, since either of A or C shall change. If only B has changed, then it must take 2ns delay while changing A shall result in 1ns delay.

Refer to [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiGtpKAnKnJAhWXc44KHbwfB_0QFggnMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.cae.wisc.edu%2F%7Eece601%2Ffall01%2Flectures%2FLecture_4_f01.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH02jdcZz36QjG72Np2llggQmP7cQ&sig2=xq4LN96U05kQZVtdekJQ-g&cad=rja) and [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiGtpKAnKnJAhWXc44KHbwfB_0QFggiMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cse.psu.edu%2F%7Evxn9%2Fverify%2Fprotected%2Fslides%2FSimulationEngine.ppt&usg=AFQjCNHLXFNzTWkS52rwKEfKNkDI-IgnRQ&sig2=YzQT5pX8I_xci_OJpfPcVA&cad=rja) material for further info.

Comment: Thanks...Would this mean that if the code looked like this
`always @ (a or b or c)
begin
x = a | b;
y = a ^ b ^ x; 
end`
Where `y` now depends on `x`, the value of `y` would be indeterminate or will have a race condition, depending on which statement is executed first?

Comment: Here, **blocking** assignment is used. So, going into sequence, `x` is evaluated and updated first. Then `y` is evaluated, so there is no in-determination.

Comment: In this document:http://cs.baylor.edu/~maurer/aida/desauto/chapter3.pdf at page 7 it says that it will take 2 time steps to execute the assignments, at  C and Q. If I use blocking statements for both the gates inside an always block, should this then execute in single time step?

Comment: @sarthak I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: What should be the code that produces 2 time step delay? Further I do not think that unit delay is assumed for the model, it is because of the way it is implemented unit delay is arising.

Comment: It's a kind of **simulation technique**. Like Level based simulation technique, Zero delay model, Unit delay model etc. That is, how the simulator interacts with the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32055/discussion-between-sarthak-and-sharvil111).