# Unrelated change causes circuit simulation delta

Tags: verilog

I'm seeing some where differences in circuit simulation when changing what should be an unrelated module. I'm trying to understand what optimizations are going on here to cause this:

```
// Multiplicand Load Register                                                                     
module mc (input  clkIn,                                                                                     
           input  rstIn,                                                                                     
           input  [7:0]multicIn,                                                                             
           input  ldMIn,                                                                                     
           output reg [7:0]multicOut);                                                                                                                                                             

  always @ (posedge clkIn)                                                                          
  begin                                                                                               
    if (rstIn)                                                                                          
      multicOut <= 8'b00000000;                                                                       
    else if (ldMIn)                                                                                     
      multicOut <= multicIn;                                                                        
  end                                                                                               
endmodule //mc                                                                                                                                                                                      

// Multiplier Shift Register                                                                      
module mp (input  clkIn,                                                                                     
           input  rstIn,                                                                                     
           input  [7:0]multipIn,                                                                             
           input  ldMIn,                                                                                     
           input  srPIn,                                                                                     
           input  irIn,                                                                                      
           output reg [7:0]prodLowOut);                                                                                                                                                             

  always @ (posedge clkIn)                                                                          
  begin                                                                                               
    if (rstIn)                                                                                          
      prodLowOut <= 8'b00000000;                                                                      
    else if (ldMIn)                                                                                      
      prodLowOut <= multipIn;                                                                         
    else if (srPIn)                                                                                     
      prodLowOut <= {irIn, prodLowOut[7:1]};                                                        
  end                                                                                               
endmodule //mp
```

If I simulate this as it is, the mc module loads a clock cycle early (seeming to infer a latch):

[image]

But if I comment out the shift register, else if srPIn, line in mp (effectively making them the same), then mc loads at the correct time:

[image]

My question is, why are changes in one module seeming to affect changes in another? Am I hitting some weird optimization area? Why am I inferring a latch where I shouldn't be? This seems to follow the correct rules for writing a register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your test bench stimulus is using blocking assignments and/or `#` delays before assigning stimulus values. Something like below.

```
initial begin
  clkIn = 1;
  forever #5 clkIn = !clkIn;
end
initial begin
  ldMIn = 1'b0;
  #20;
  ldMIn = 1'b1;
  #10;
  ldMIn = 1'b0;
end
```

The above example allows for a race condition in the Verilog scheduler. `ldMIn` and `clkIn` become one in the same time step, but the assignment and evaluation order is not deterministic. In your first waveform, `ldMIn` is being assigned before `mc` is triggred by the `@(posedge clkIn)` which is why `multicOut` is updated immediately. In the, in the second waveform the scheduler happened to reverse the order.

The Verilog language specifically allows non-determinism (up the to the vender how to implement). Making it your responsibility to enforce determinism when needed. The easiest way to do this in the test-bench is to use non-blocking assignment for synchronous data, just like RTL does. (See [Blocking vs Non Blocking Assignments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/222788/17779) )

Assigning `ldMIn` and other non-clock synchronous signals with non-blocking should fix your issue. I would highly suggest one additional change; delay the assignments relative to `@(posedge clkIn)` instead of `#` delays. Doing so forces any assignment to be after the clock update and allows for easy scaling with the clock frequency.

```
initial begin
  clkIn = 1;
  forever #5 clkIn = !clkIn;
end
initial begin
  ldMIn = 1'b0; // blocking assignment okay for time 0 initialization
  #1; // tiny delay to mask possible posedge (x->1 transition) at time 0
  repeat(2) @(posedge clkIn); // delay relative to clock edge; not time
  ldMIn <= 1'b1; // non-blocking assignment 
  @(posedge clkIn); // delay realitve to clock
  ldMIn <= 1'b0; // non-blocking assignment
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a bunch in clarifying blocking vs nonblocking and I never thought it would actually matter in the testbench. I come from a mostly VHDL background and I've never encountered anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are changing your input values and the clock at exactly the same time, although we would need to see your testbench to be sure. That's a dangerous thing to do in real life or in a simulation. Try moving the changes in the input values by about a quarter of the clock period, after the rising clock edge.