# What difference do blocking and non-blocking assignments have on a single-line assign statement?

Tags: verilog

```
always @(posedge clk)
       count = count+1;
```

and

```
   always @(posedge clk)
           count <= count+1;
```

what difference do the above codes have in simulation? I get that the synthesis will yield the same result, but what changes occur for one-line assignment simulation when using blocking and non-blocking assignments.
A similar question was asked some while ago [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/401092/blocking-and-nonblocking-statements-for-counter). But I am not satisfied with the answer there, and since I am low on reputations, I could not comment there.
Please note that I know the difference between blocking and non-blocking assignments. I just need to know the difference when it comes to one-liners.

Comment: In complete isolation, no context at all, and where there is only one statement in the always block? I'm not sure anyone can help much. But [this EESE link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/91688/38098) carries discussions that may help you, more broadly.

Answer (score 0):

The difference has nothing to do whether there is one one line or a block of code. If count is being read by another process synchronized to the same positive edge of clock, you have a race condition as to whether you're reading the new or updated value.

This code could be in the same module or connected to another module.

```
always @(posedge clk)
         zero = (count == 0);
```

Although synthesis treats this as "`zero` will be true the the cycle after `count` is 0", `zero` might get ahead by one cycle in simulation if it reads the updated value to soon.

You should my recent post "[SystemVerilog Race Condition Challenge Responses](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2020/08/13/systemverilog-race-condition-challenge-responses/)"